# Determine the group structure from its character table: a group of order $24$ as an example

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, sylow-theory, characters, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a finite group and the following is its character table (of irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations):
$$
\begin{matrix} 
&g_1=1&g_2&g_3&g_4&g_5&g_6&g_7\\
\hline
\chi_1 &1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\chi_2 &1&1&1&\omega^2&\omega&\omega^2&\omega \\
\chi_3 &1&1&1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega&\omega^2 \\
\chi_4 &2&-2&0&-1&-1&1&1\\
\chi_5 &2&-2&0&-\omega^2&-\omega&\omega^2&\omega\\
\chi_6 &2&-2&0&-\omega&-\omega^2&\omega&\omega^2\\
\chi_7 &3&3&-1&0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}$$

**My question is how to prove:** $G$ is the semi-direct product of its Sylow 2-subgroup and its Sylow 3-subgroup.

---

**My knowledge on this group**:

- The order of $G$: $24$. [By the square sum of the first column]
- Number of elements $m_i$ in each conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}_{g_i}$ with representative $g_i$: $(m_i)=(1,1,6,4,4,4,4)$.
- Kernel of each irreducible repn $\pi_i$ with character $\chi_i$:
  $$
  \ker \pi_1=G, \,  \ker \pi_2=\ker \pi_3 = \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_3}, \,  \ker \pi_7 = \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2}
  $$
  and the remaining representations are faithful (i.e. with trivial kernel).
- Normal subgroups: $\{1\}, \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2}, \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_3}, G$. They are of order $1,2,8,24$ respectively.
- Commutator subgroup: $[G,G] = \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_3}$ of order $8$.
- Center: $Z(G)= \mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2}$ of order $2$.
- Sylow $2$-subgroup (of order $8$): there is already a *normal* subgroup $[G,G]$ of order $8$. So this is the unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. Call it $P$.
- Sylow $3$-subgroups (of order $3$): since there is no normal subgroup of order $3$, there are more than one Sylow $3$-subgroup. By Sylow theorem, there are four Sylow $3$-subgroups, which are all isomorphic to $C_3$, the cyclic group of order $3$. Call them $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4$.

**BUT I got stuck here** to go any further to the show $G = P \rtimes Q_i$ for some $i$.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: The group is isomorphic to $SL(2,3)$ by the way.

Comment: @NickyHekster Sorry for such a late reply, but may I ask how did you see that this is the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$? I searched information of the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ on [groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/SL(2,3)). Properties of $G$ I get from the character table coincides with the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$. So I believe that. But as character tables may *not* determine the group structure (e.g. $D_4$ and $Q_8$ case), how can I see *mathematically* (instead of by faith) that this group is indeed $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$? Thank you so much!

Comment: (maybe one can classify the groups of order 24, draw all these character tables and see that none of these coincide, so $G \cong \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$? But this is obviously too complicated.)

Comment: Good point! It requires some more inspection indeed. From the character table one can derive that $G$ is solvable of derived length 3. There is only one other group of order $24$ having this property (see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_24) : $S_4$. But that group has an integer valued character table. So your character table is unique in the sense that is characterizes $SL(2,3)$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you! Here is how I get the derived length of $G$ from the character table: as $[G,G]$ is the intersection of kernels of one-dimensional reps, from the table we see that $[G,G]=\mathcal{C}_{g_1} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_2} \cup \mathcal{C}_{g_3}$ is of order 8. It is nonabelian otherwise it would be a union of 8 classes. So **by classification of group of order 8**, it has to be $D_4$ or $Q_8$. Then both $D_4$ and $Q_8$ has derived subgroup $C_2 \times C_2$, which is abelian. Hence to sum up, $G$ has derived length 3.

Comment: @NickyHekster  Yet again we invoke the classification of groups of order 8, so this is not **purely-"character-table-theoretical"**. Is this what in your mind when concluding that $G$ has derived length 3? Or there is some method to get the derived length directly from the character table? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Not sure you are familiar with Itô's Theorem: if $A \unlhd G$ abelian, then $\chi(1) \mid |G:A|$ for all $\chi \in Irr(G)$. This shows that $G'$ cannot be abelian (the group has degree $2$ irreducible characters) and in fact $G''=Z(G)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you for introducing Ito's theorem to me! I know a similar result of Serre (or attributed to Tate) that for all irreducible characters $\chi$, $\chi(1) \mid [G:Z(G)]$, yet haven't seen Ito's result before. And for the result $G^{\prime\prime}=Z(G)$, I remember an exercise in group theory: **If a nonabelian group is of order $p^3$ for some prime $p$, then  $G^{\prime} = Z(G)$.** I can apply it here since $G^{\prime}$ is of order 8. Thank you for remind me of that!

Comment: @NickyHekster Your comments are really helpful to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: The result you quote goes back to I. Schur and his student Frobenius. I have a shortcut for your second remark: as you noticed $Z(G) \subseteq G'$, and $|G':Z(G)|=4$, hence $G'/Z(G)$ is abelian (all groups of prime square order are abelian!), implying $G'' \subseteq Z(G)$. Since $|Z(G)|=2$ and $G'' \gt 1$, we must have $G''=Z(G)$. Good luck, I guess this conversation stops here otherwise we will be summoned to go to the StackExchange facility for this ...

Comment: @NickyHekster  Haha, thank you for your hint! :)

Comment: In the above comment, I made a **mistake**: the derived subgroup of both $D_4$ and $Q_8$ are $C_2$, not $C_2 \times C_2$. Given the presentation $$D_4 = \langle a,b \mid a^4=1=b^2, bab=a^3 \rangle ,$$ the derived subgroup $D_4^{\prime} = \langle a^2 \rangle$. And given the presentation $$Q_8 = \langle i,j,k \mid i^2=j^2 = k^2 = ijk \rangle ,$$ the derived subgroup $Q_8^{\prime}$ is $\{1, -1 \}$. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know that $P$ is normal, all that is left to prove that $Q_1 P = G$ and $Q_1 \cap P =1$, using the characterization of internal semidirect products. Both of these follow from order considerations (i.e. Lagrange).

More generally, if a Sylow subgroup in a group is normal, we get a semidirect product decomopsition by Schur-Zassenhaus. (Though that's overkill here.)

Comment: Thank you! The thing is that I'm so unfamiliar with "semi-direct product". :(   Thank you so much!

Comment: And thank you for pointing out the "Schur-Zassenhaus"! :)